# Nextjs and Passport authentication: Failed to deserialize user out of session

Tags: next.js, passport.js, express-session

After trying for a couple of days i need some help.

I'm setting up authentication in my nextjs app with passport. After login the session is stored in my database and the user object is on the req object.
The problem is that after browser or server restart, it returns error message "Failed to deserialize user out of session" when using the auth.js middleware.

Endpoint for logging in user

```
// pages/api/auth/login.js

import nextConnect from 'next-connect'
import '../../../lib/passport-local'
import passport from 'passport'
import auth from '../../../middleware/auth'
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
require('dotenv').config();

const handler = nextConnect()

handler.use(auth).post(
  (req, res) => {
    passport.authenticate(
      'local',
      (err, user, {message}) => {
        try {
          if (err || !user) {
            return res.json({ error: message });
          }
          req.login(
            user,
            (error) => {
              if (error) return res.json({ error });

              let { id, email, firstname, lastname } = user
              return res.json({message: "Logged in",user: {id, email, firstname, lastname} });
            }
          );
          // let { id, email, firstname, lastname } = user
          // return res.json({message: "Logged in",user: {id, email, firstname, lastname} });
        } catch (error) {
            return res.json({error});
        }
      }
    )(req, res);
  }
```

---

Passport strategy:

```
// lib/passport-local.js
 
import passport from 'passport'
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const  Sequelize  = require('sequelize');
const models = require('./../db/models/index');

require('dotenv').config();

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password'
},
  async (email, password, done) => {
    try {
        let user = await models.User.findByMail(email) || false
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, {message: 'User not found'} );
        }
        const validate = await user.isValidPassword(password);
        if (!validate) {
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Wrong Password'} );
        }        
        return done(null, user, {message: 'Logged in Successfully'} );
    } catch (error) {
      return done(error);
    }
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    try{
      let user = await models.User.findByPk(id)

      done(null, {id: user.id, firstname: user.firstname, lastname: user.lastname, email: user.email});
    } catch (error) {
      done(error);
    }

});
```

---

Auth middleware:

```
// middelware/auth.js

import nextConnect from 'next-connect'
import passport from 'passport'
import db from './../db/models/index'
var session = require('express-session');
var SequelizeStore = require("connect-session-sequelize")(session.Store);

var myStore = new SequelizeStore({
  db: db.sequelize,
  checkExpirationInterval: 15 * 60 * 1000, // The interval at which to cleanup expired sessions in milliseconds.
  expiration: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000  // The maximum age (in milliseconds) of a valid session.
})

const auth = nextConnect()
  .use(
    session({
      name: 'as-auth',
      saveUninitialized:true,
      secret: process.env.TOKEN_SECRET,
      store: myStore,
      resave: false,
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1000 hours,
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        path: '/',
        sameSite: 'lax',
      },
    })
  )
  .use(passport.initialize())
  .use(passport.session())
  myStore.sync();

export default auth
```

---

Endpoint for checking if user is logged in

```
// pages/api/auth/loggedin.js

import nextConnect from 'next-connect'
import auth from '../../../middleware/auth'

const handler = nextConnect()

handler
  .use(auth)
  .get((req, res) => {
    res.json({ user: req.user })
  })

export default handler
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED: it was because i forgot to import passport-local in middelware/auth.js, so my middleware didn't have the serialize and deserialize functions.